# Automatically notify my app when a photo is taken/added

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am developing a mobile application for Android using Cordova/AngularJS. My application needs to be notified when a photo has been taken or added to the photo gallery.

Because I am a newbie at both Cordova and Android, I do not have a clue of how to do that. I did not found any relevant Cordova plugin who could help me on that nor any solution on the web.

I read about [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) class that could maybe help me with that, but I really do not know where and how to start.

How would you handle my needs?

Comment: Please, I am realy stuck. Is anyone here that could help me ? :'(

Answer (score 0):

Note: I donot know any think about cordova only plain android-java.

The sourcecode of [FineGeotag](https://github.com/M66B/FineGeotag) does exactly what you want: it adds gps-data to every new photo taken and it works great on my android 4.4 phone.

Unfortunately the author says that [FineGeoTag is not supported anymore](https://github.com/M66B/FineGeotag/pull/7) because this is not compatible with newer android verstions.

[See here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html#media-broadcasts) for details:

Pre android-7.0 apps can register broadcasts for [ACTION_NEW_PICTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE)

Android-7.0 and up should use [JobInfo api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html) instead.

I have not tried it myself.

Comment: I really hate hate hate how Google decides to just delete perfectly good functionality because they think they know better than us.  I would not be constantly slamming Google if they respected my choice e.g. here whether or not to accept the battery life consequences in return for the functionality I need.